# Turn a restricted composition (or partition) into a unique index

Tags: combinatorics

I'm interested in the restricted compositions of a number $N$ ($\le$ 13, often exactly 13) into at most $M$ (always 4) parts.  If it helps, I can consider the restricted partitions first, and I can also consider 2, 3 and 4 parts separately.

I imagine the compositions as a list with $C$ entries where each composition has an index $1 \ldots C$.  I can of course control the order of the entries.

Given a particular restricted composition, say 4-6-1-2 or 0-4-5-4, I want to be able to compute its index efficiently, without having to search through the list.

Is there an order and a formula that enables this?

All the literature on compositions and partitions that I've seen is concerned with generating them efficiently and in a given order, sometimes linked with Gray codes.  So I wonder:  Is there a way to get from, say, a composition to a Gray code to an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $f(n,k)=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ weak compositions of $n$ into $k$ non-negative parts.

Consider the **dictionary-order** list of weak compositions of 13 into 4 non-negative parts. It begins 0-0-0-13, 0-0-1-12, 0-0-2-11, ... 0-0-13-0, 0-1-0-12, 0-1-1-11, ... and contains $\tbinom{16}3=560$ entries.
Where is 4-6-1-2 in this list?

Well, every composition starting with 0, 1, 2, or 3 comes before it. If you cross out the initial number, you get weak compositions of 13, 12, 11, and 10 into 3 parts. That makes $$f(13,3)+f(12,3)+f(11,3)+f(10,3)=\tbinom{15}2+\tbinom{14}2+\tbinom{13}2+\tbinom{12}2=340$$
After that comes every composition starting with 4- followed by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5: $$f(9,2)+f(8,2)+\ldots+f(4,2)=\sum_{i=5}^{10}\tbinom{i}1=45$$
Then every composition starting with 4-6- followed by 0: $f(3,1)=\binom30=1$.

The sum is $340+45+1=386$, so 4-6-1-2 is the $387$th weak composition in the list.

---

Now, by the hockey-stick identity, $$\tbinom{15}2+\tbinom{14}2+\tbinom{13}2+\tbinom{12}2\quad =\quad \tbinom{16}3-\tbinom{12}3$$
Applying this all the way down the line, the conclusion is that the position of $a_0a_1a_2...a_{k-1}$ in the dictionary-order list of $f(n,k)$ weak compositions is
$$1+\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\binom{n+k-1-j-\sum_{p=0}^{j-1}a_p}{k-1-j}-\binom{n+k-1-j-\sum_{p=0}^{j}a_p}{k-1-j}$$
which looks a lot more complicated than it actually is: it's the sum of $2k-2$ binomials. When $n=13$ and $k=4$, the formula is $$1+\tbinom{16}3-\tbinom{16-a_0}{3}+\tbinom{15-a_0}{2}-\tbinom{15-a_0-a_1}{2}+\tbinom{14-a_0-a_1}{1}-\tbinom{14-a_0-a_1-a_2}{1}$$
$$=\tfrac16((a_0^2-45a_0+674-6a_1)a_0-3a_1(a_1-29)+6a_2+6)$$
$$=561+a_2-\tfrac16(15-a_0)(14-a_0)(13-a_0)-\tfrac12(15-a_0-a_1)(14-a_0-a_1)$$

The last version is probably the easiest to implement.

You can verify it in Python (notice that indexing here starts with 0):

```
def weakcomp(n,k):
    if k==1:return [[n]]
    return [[m]+p for m in range(n+1) for p in weakcomp(n-m,k-1)]

L=weakcomp(13,4) # --- list of 560 lists

def f(x,y,z):
    return 560+z-(15-x)*(14-x)*(13-x)//6-(15-x-y)*(14-x-y)//2
```

Obviously, in very time-critical situations you could just declare a block of $14^3=2744$ cells, index by $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$, and accept that 80% will remain empty. I suspect that many programmers would feel that the formula is too opaque to be worth using.

Comment: Oh excellent.  And quite simple.  Thank you for taking the time to figure this out.